# Replace selected characters

Tags: sed

How can one replace only the first `[:space:]` character in each row of a file with a `\t` using `sed`?

```
Input: 
AC 12 45
DC 56 89

Expected output:
AC    12 45
DC    56 89
```

(Something like `sed  "s/[:space]/'\t'/g"` but without affecting the other spaces in the row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply a substitution to only the first match on each line, you just need to remove the `g` (global) modifier e.g.

```
sed 's/ /\t/' input
```

(the POSIX class `[[:space:]]` is overkill for your requirement, since it includes the tab character).

---

FYI the GNU version of `sed` has some additional capabilities e.g. specifying which match to substitute explicitly via a number e.g.

```
$ sed 's/ /\t/1' input
AC      12 45
DC      56 89
$ sed 's/ /\t/2' input
AC 12   45
DC 56   89
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `g`:

```
sed 's/ /\t/' file
```

without `g`, sed only match the first occurence in line.